# VS Code: How to refactor(rename variable) in an Angular template file?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-template

I want to rename a variable used across an angular template file (i.e. an ***xxx.component.html*** file). This could be done with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> shortcut in WebStorm. How to do it in vscode? <kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>  combination to select the word and then type the new word , It will select all and replace with the new one

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Yep, note you can also use ctrl+shift+p to show commands. Type replace and hit enter. I often use this for keycombos I forget/rarely use (e.g. join onto one line, git file history, etc.).

Comment: this will change just the occurrences inside the template, and won't refactor the variable inside the component class (`.ts` file), so the true `Shift + F6` shortcut is not available as far as I know